# Ocelot request not going through the desired priority

Tags: .net-core, microservices, ocelot

I have implemented Ocelot API gateway in my project

```
{
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/{suffix}",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 5001
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/admin/v1/{suffix}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Get", "Post", "Put", "Delete", "Patch" ],
      "RequestIdKey": "admin",
      "Priority": 2
    },
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/{version}/{suffix}",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 5001
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/admin/{version}/{suffix}",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Get", "Post", "Put", "Delete", "Patch" ],
      "RequestIdKey": "admin",
      "Priority": 1
    }
```

[API Endpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RfPw.png)

When I tried to send POST request,
for the v1 version, `v1/app/regions/{regionid}/schools`, gives 200 response

but for the v2 version, `v2/app/regions/{regionid}/schools`, gives 404 response

instead this works, `v1/v2/app/regions/{regionid}/schools`, I don't how/why this works.

Please let me know what I should change in ocelot.json file or controllers?

I did try deploying gateway again, but nothing worked.

Comment: can you try with priority: 0 in the below route admin/{version} one.